# Are there any special event hooks for joomla modules

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have been searching special event hooks for use to track and update module forms. I found contenthooks on the documentation site but I couldn't get anything for modules. I want to add a plugin so that it adds an extra field viz. radio button to every module form. Finally I want to use the value of this radio field in templates/your-template/html/module.php. Can someone point me in the right direction towards this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Jooma does not have event driven structure like for example .NET or Java. However if you want to trigger some additional functionality on certain event you may create a plugin. Plugin is something different than module or component but it 'collaborates' with them. It handles some per-defined events:
[http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events][1]

[1]: http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events and it lets you define your own.

You may also try the way I usually take which is customize module display. You simply copy

view file of the module you want to modify to your template. For example:

```
/modules/mod_feed/tmpl/default.php
```

to

```
/templates/{your template}/mod_feed/default.php
```

Now you can freely modify this file without any risk that it may be overwritten on the next Joomla update. Just don't forget to set your overwrite in module settings: go to administrator, modules, choose module to edit and in the tab 'Advanced' select 'Alternative Layout'.

I hope this helps and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the new com_ajax that is in 3.2.